# How to create a table in JSX dialog box for supporting every versions in Photoshop (2014, 2015, 2017) using photoshop scrpting?

Tags: jsx, photoshop-script

I created a table for JSX dialog box using **Multi column list** in Photoshop scripting as below.

```
var dlg = new Window("dialog", "Student List");  
dlg.frameLocation = [100,100]; // position  
dlg.size = [750, 250];  


//table initailize   
var w0=150, w1=150 ;  

table = dlg.add ("listbox", {x:20, y:20, width:300, height:150}, undefined, { numberOfColumns:2, showHeaders:true,   
 columnWidths: [w0,w1],   
 columnTitles:["First Name", "Last Name"] });  


table.add("item", "Namodaya");   
table.items[0].subItems[0].text = "Balaarachchi";  

 dlg.show();
```

The following table was outputted when I run it on Photoshop 2014.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFzY6.png]

But when I try it using Photoshop 2015, table was not displayed and error was occurred. Then I searched about it.

According to my observation, **Multi column list** was not supported for 2015 and later Photoshop versions.
Please suggest me, how to create table for supporting every Photoshop version in JSX dialog box using Photoshop scripting.

Comment: Might want to reference where you concluded that multi-column tables should work. I get the same error you describe running CS 2018 (version 19). I am guessing from the ScriptUI document here: [Photoshop ScriptUI](http://www.joshwright.com/tips/photoshop-scripting-user-interface)

Comment: PS. The error I get is "Error -36: Not implemented... subItems[...." which implies the feature was removed.